# Почему присваивание значения readonly свойству не вызывает ошибки?

Tags: javascript

В JavaScript можно определить свойство, доступное только для чтения (readonly). Однако, если я пытаюсь переопределить значение такого свойства, то ничего не происходит. Значение остается прежним, но и исключение не выбрасывается.

Пример кода:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'val', {
    writable: false,
    value: 'foo'
});

obj.val = 'bar';
console.log(obj.val); // Выведет 'foo';
```

Почему так происходит, и как сделать так, чтобы подобные ошибки не замалчивались?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможность определять свойства, доступные только для чтения появилась *относительно* недавно, в ES5. Поэтому, в целях обратной совместимости со старым кодом, JavaScript специально замалчивает подобные ошибки.

Если вы хотите, чтобы подобные ошибки не замалчивались, используйте [строгий режим](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var obj = {};
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'val', {
        writable: false,
        value: 'foo'
    });

    obj.val = 'bar'; // [TypeError]: "val" is read-only
    console.log(obj.val);
})();
```

Более подробно, поведение оператора присваивания описано в спецификации [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Помимо прочего, в блоке "Note" сказано, что исключение должно выбрасываться только в строгом режиме.

> When an assignment occurs within strict mode code <...> the *LeftHandSide* may not be a reference to a data property with the attribute value {[[Writable]]:**false**}, to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:**undefined**}, nor to a non-existent property of an object for which the IsExtensible predicate returns the value **false**. In these cases a **TypeError** exception is thrown.